# How is data exchanged between Eurocontrol and FAA?

Tags: flight-planning, faa

Let's say I want to fly from Europe to USA.

Then (probably):

1. I'm filling flight plan message(FPS) and it goes to Eurocontrol system.
2. It is somehow transmitted to FAA. How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flight plans are distributed to all air traffic control units that will be providing services along the route over the [Aeronautical Fixed Telecom Network (AFTN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronautical_Fixed_Telecommunication_Network).

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays most communications between Europe and the US is over AMHS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronautical_Message_Handling_System)